# Add variable as value in schedule ANYLOGIC

Tags: anylogic

In my model I use a schedule to define the capacity of a transporter fleet. Now I want the capacity to be a variable which can change based on the user input, but when I want to type the variable name (see red circle in inmage) in the value function of schedule block this will not work is there a method to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to so this is to use the load from database option and read in the values from the database.

Alternative is to create the schedules programmatically

Comment: Thanks @Jaco-Ben, than I'm going to try it progammatically.

Comment: Check this question for creating a schedule programmatically - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67674139/error-by-create-schedule-programmatically 
But it should all be in the API documents in the help

Comment: Thanks @Jaco-Ben Vosloo, I now run into a new problem, which I asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72227242/changing-transporterfleet-based-on-progammaticaly-created-schedule-anylogic