# Changing transporterfleet based on programmaticaly created schedule

Tags: anylogic

In following up related to my previous question [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72217914/add-variable-as-value-in-schedule-anylogic/72218970?noredirect=1#comment127608155_72218970), when a schedule programmatically is created, where I run the function at the start-up of my main (see image 1), I want to change the transporterfleet (image2) schedule based on this. But when I do this by the initschedule function the next error is given " The parameter capacitySchedule cannot be changed dynamically". So my question is how can you use a programmatically created schedule use in the capacity definition of a transporter fleet?

[image]

[image]

Later added in response to Benjamin

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Capacity field, write `schedule == null ? 0. : schedule.getValue()`

This will link it to your programmatic schedule, but only after it has been created (which is not done right at the start of the model but an instance later).

Comment: If I do this and set capacity defined to by schedule it gives the error: cannot convert from double to Schedule. . If I do it by directly and sets this, it still says the rror cannot change it dynamically, I've added images to the begin post of the two options. I Tried both 0. (double) and 0(integer)

Comment: I referred to the original screenshot field "capacity". If you switch to "capacity defined by Schedule", then the field Schedule needs to read `schedule` only. If this throws an error on start, create a normal fakeSchedule with some fake data. in the field write `schedule == null ? fakeSchedule : schedule`. Understand what data types different fields want and what those errrors mean to fix them yourself in the future :)