# AnyLogic: Changing ResourcePool based on programmatically created schedule

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I refer to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72227242/changing-transporterfleet-based-on-programmaticaly-created-schedule).

I implemented a programmatically created schedule same as in the example model from AnyLogic Cloud. Then I added the suggested code in the capacity field.

Still, my problem is the following runtime error: "The parameter capacitySchedule cannot be changed dynamically". Does it just basically does not work with the resource pool compared to the Transporter Fleet presented in the similar problem? Unfortunately it does not work with a fake schedule either.

Here are some screenshots from my model. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Likely something else. You are not showing the parameter `capacitySchedule`, how and where do you use it?

Comment: Now I'm a little confused. I have not created a capacitySchedule parameter. I just created the variable `schedule` as in the AnyLogic Cloud example as type of Schedule<Integer>.

Comment: `.set_capacitySchedule(...)` is an anylogic internal method isn't it?

Comment: sorry, my bad. So the error is telling you what the problem is: you cannot use the  `set_capacitySchedule` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with dynamic capacity of ResourcePool, I use a schedule shift by plan.
in some cases it meets the need.
The implementation of this is simple, in the schedule you give values 1,2,3 etc. They actually point to a position in the array.

[Example of the schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlkAP.png)

And inside the ResourcePool you define it as follows:

[Example of the ResourcePool by plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUtTv.png)

In my example, at times when the schedule value is 4 the capacity of the ResourcePool is 0 and at other times it is as per my parameters.

Comment: That's a very good idea, thank you! Maybe I will use it in my model, but I would prefer the start and end time of my shifts modifiable as a parameter as well. And I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that's not possible with your suggest?

Comment: I think it is possible.
Try to build a function according to your needs, that returns a schedule.
In the ResourcePool settings, select the value option and call the function there.
For more detail on the ResourcePool parameters learn [here](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/resourcepool.html#parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Change the "Kapaziät definiert" to "By schedule".
Create a fake schedule object `fakeSchedule` (normally, not programmatically). Make sure it always returns 0 as the value.

Then, use this call for "Kapazität":

' mySchedule == null ? fakeSchedule : mySchedule`

This will tell the pool to use your schedule if it exists, else the fake one

Comment: Unfortunately I still get this error. What am I doing wrong?! As an Example I chose a size of 5. 
 Here a screenshot of my ResourcePool: https://imgur.com/a/LXcz4wg
And here a screenshot of my fake schedule: https://imgur.com/a/tzYKNAr
Did I implement smth wrong? I assumed I did erverything you suggested...